# How to refactor these class extensions in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

State1, State2 and State3 all have the same constructor.  How can I simplify things so that I don't need to have constructors within State1, State2 and State3?

```
public class State1 : State{

    public State1( StateMachine owner ) : base( owner ){
    }
}

public class State2 : State{

    public State2( StateMachine owner ) : base( owner ){
    }
}

public class State3 : State{

    public State3( StateMachine owner ) : base( owner ){
    }
}
```

So far the best solution I can find is:

```
        State1 s1 = new State( this ) as State1;
        State1 s2 = new State( this ) as State2;
        State1 s3 = new State( this ) as State3;
```

But it looks messy.

Comment: That "solution" will leave all three variables as `null`...

Comment: `simplify` do mean write less code or see less code?

Answer (score 4):

If you want them to indeed be subclasses of `State` then no, there is no easier way than this, at least not one that would be correct and follow good design patterns.

And your proposed solution actually does not work the way you think it does.  It will create three `State` objects and attempt to cast them as the indicated subclass.  This will fail, and the `as` operator will evaluate to `null` in all three cases.

Comment: I un-upvoted because it appears to me like the OP might want to be able to do `State1 s1 = new State1( this )`, except without explicitly declaring a new constructor on each class that derives from `State`

Comment: @SamIam That will only work if the parent class has its own no-arg constructor, and assuming that you do not need to pass any initial values.  (So, for example, if `StateMachine` were a singleton... which would be bad.)

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't really much need for you to be doing this... and there is no way to avoid having to repeat constructors if they really need to be constructors. But, if you can get away with using object initializers you may not need to have the constructors at all. So you could just use the paramterless constructor and construct your objects like this:

```
var state1 = new State1() { Owner = this };
var state2 = new State2() { Owner = this };
var state3 = new State3() { Owner = this };
```

Comment: Note that if the states are designed to be immutable, this cannot reasonably work.  (It's hard to say for sure without seeing the rest of the various state classes.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you want to execute a constructor in your base class that has one or more parameters, you must implement the equivalent constuctor in your derived class.

To remove any lingering doubt, here it is from the [horse's mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx):

> When you define a class to derive from another class, the derived
>   class implicitly gains all the members of the base class, except for
>   its constructors and destructors.

One thing you COULD do, BUT without knowing anything more about your application, I leave it to you to judge whether this is safe or advisable: make `Owner` a static property of `State`. This will enable you to use code such as

```
 State.Owner = this;

 State1 s1 = new State1();
 State2 s2 = new State2();
 State3 s3 = new State3();
```

In your derived classes you'll then access `Owner` as `State.Owner`.